# Text editor remembers new files without explicity saving to disk

Tags: text-editor

I'm searching for a texteditor (similar to notepad++) if I write a text in a new (unsaved) file and close this texteditor (or crashes), the file is still here if I reopen notepad++, without ever saving it explicitly to disk. Of course has to be saved to disk somehow (maybe in a temp-folder), but it is imho stored there only as long as the file is open.

Any linux-texteditor (without wine) I know I have to save the file on disk first before closing the application, which is annoying if you want to restart/shut down the computer, or it is a temporary text, which you do not want to explicitly save to disk (and you have to delete afterwards).

Comment: This post is looking for *opinions*, which isn't too popular on AskUbuntu, but I'll happily recommend Sublime Text 3 to anyone and everyone who will listen. The application will do everything you're looking for and then some. Many people will scoff at the $100 license, but it's worth it. That said, the application does not force you to get a license. You always have full access to all of the features 

Comment: by all accounts notepad++ does save to disk [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49870478/how-does-notepad-save-file-to-the-disk). It can't remain in volatile memory such as RAM without there being a power source. It's just that it happens behind the scenes as it were without user specific intervention.

Comment: @Matigo Thank you for your comment! Would you like to make a proper answer, that I can marked it as solved?

Comment: @JoKalliauer the comment by Matigo has disappeared, would you post an answer yourself if you solved the issue?

Answer (score 0):

1. [Atom](https://atom.io/) does this, but since Github (which developed it) was bought by Microsoft, they're killing it off so we'll be forced to go to their cloud services.
2. [Sublime Text](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sublime_Text) does it, but I'm searching for a replacement because it has lost a ton of my data by occasionally NOT preserving buffers I was counting on.

I am trying to find a third way, but those are the two I know of right now.